# How to optimize and tune hadoop cluster performance

Tags: hadoop

I am not very familiar with hadoop cluster configs and I have recently integrated Apache Nutch with Apache Hadoop and I have crawled data indexed in Solr successfully.
I have my master-slave sources as below:

Master:
CPU : 4 cores
memory :12G
hard disk : 37G

Slave1 : 
CPU : 2 cores
memory :4G
hard disk : 18G

Slave2: 
CPU : 2 cores
memory :4G
hard disk : 16G

Slave3 : 
CPU : 2 cores
memory :4G
hard disk : 16G

Slave4 : 
CPU : 4 cores
memory :4G
hard disk : 50G

I have configed core-site.xml, mapred-site.xml, hdfs-site.xml, masters and slaves.

Here is my core-site.xml :

```html
<configuration> 
        <property> 
                <name>hadoop.tmp.dir</name> 
                <value>/usr/local/My Project Name/hadoop-datastore</value> 
                <description>store data</description> 
        </property> 

        <property> 
                <name>fs.default.name</name> 
                <value>hdfs://master:54310</value> 
                <description>the name of default file system</description> 
        </property>    
</configuration>
```

Here is my mapred-site.xml :

```html
<configuration> 
  <property> 
    <name>mapred.job.tracker</name> 
    <value>master:54311</value> 
    <description>host and port</description> 
  </property> 

  <property> 
    <name>mapred.reduce.tasks</name> 
    <value>10</value> 
    <description></description> 
  </property> 

  <property> 
    <name>mapred.map.tasks</name> 
    <value>20</value> 
    <description></description> 
  </property> 

  <property> 
    <name>mapred.tasktracker.map.tasks.maximum</name> 
    <value>8</value> 
    <description></description> 
  </property> 

  <property> 
    <name>mapred.tasktracker.reduce.tasks.maximum</name> 
    <value>8</value> 
    <description></description> 
  </property> 
</configuration>
```

And here is my hdfs-site.xml:

```html
<configuration> 
    <property> 
            <name>dfs.replication</name> 
            <value>2</value> 
            <description>default block</description> 
        </property> 

</configuration>
```

And here is my conf/masters :

```html
master
```

And finally my conf/slaves:

```html
master
slave1
slave2
slave3
slave4
```

This story goes well: When I run master and run the Jps command, I have the folowings on master:

```html
19031 TaskTracker
18644 DataNode
18764 SecondaryNameNode
18884 JobTracker
13226 Jps
18506 NameNode
```

And when I run the Jps command on all the slaves, I have the followings:

```html
4969 DataNode
5057 TaskTracker
5592 Jps
```

When I look at Master Hadoop Map/Reduce administration I have the following Cluster Summary:

```html
<h2>Cluster Summary (Heap Size is 114.5 MB/889 MB)</h2>
<table border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
<tr><th>Running Map Tasks</th><th>Running Reduce Tasks</th><th>Total Submissions</th><th>Nodes</th><th>Occupied Map Slots</th><th>Occupied Reduce Slots</th><th>Reserved Map Slots</th><th>Reserved Reduce Slots</th><th>Map Task Capacity</th><th>Reduce Task Capacity</th><th>Avg. Tasks/Node</th><th>Blacklisted Nodes</th><th>Graylisted Nodes</th><th>Excluded Nodes</th></tr>
<tr><td>8</td><td>8</td><td>1607</td><td><a href="machines.jsp?type=active">1</a></td><td>8</td><td>8</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>8</td><td>8</td><td>16.00</td><td><a href="machines.jsp?type=blacklisted">0</a></td><td><a href="machines.jsp?type=graylisted">0</a></td><td><a href="machines.jsp?type=excluded">0</a></td></tr></table>
<br>
```

The problem is this procedure works fine with topN :1000 but There is load on master with high cpu and memory usage but when I find top on slaves, Neither cpu nor  memory has loads. I mean both cpu and memory usage is low and cpu idle is high.

I wonder whether it is natural and OK or not. I am looking for some solutions and configs so that I am able to share the load on all slaves and make the procedure faster. 
Any links, documentations and solutions are very much appreciated.

Comment: Did you consider using any hadoop management system? You could easily setup a cluster using Cloudera Express for example - http://www.cloudera.com/content/cloudera/en/products-and-services/cloudera-express.html

Comment: It says `Nodes 1`, you should look into the logs of your slaves, not at the `jps`.

Comment: Actually, Thomas Jungblut ,I checked the logs and I have the error below:
 hadoop-hduser-datanode-satra-machine-slave1.log
and here is the error content :
2015-05-02 11:09:27,955 FATAL org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Shutting down. Incompatible version or revision.DataNode version '1.2.1' and revi$
2015-05-02 11:09:28,057 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: java.io.IOException: Shutting down. Incompatible version or revision.DataNode ver$
org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.startDataNode(DataNode.java:391)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an error about version 1.2.1 looking deeply at logs directory, saying this version is a 1.2.1 snapshot version. So I changed the server, installing simply version 1.2.1 and making all slaves and master similar in version. That fixed my problem. Now happily I have five nodes equal to the count of my machines.

And I really thank ... for his greate help

Answer (score 0):

Your master node is running a lot of services :

> TaskTracker DataNode SecondaryNameNode JobTracker NameNode

Typically in a decent sized cluster the Master would not have the datanode service.

Name Node & secondary Name node should be on different nodes. You can set secondary name node on one of your data nodes.

Similarly Task Tracker - Master typically does not have task Tracker. I.e. you do not run MR tasks on Master.

On the other hand for pure experimentation the setup you have done is ok & the CPU usage you are noticing is obvious.